# Are Bamboo server configuration questions on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Recently a [question came up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27064613/can-bamboo-deploy-to-a-server-with-only-an-internal-ip?noredirect=1#comment42643301_27064613) about [bamboo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bamboo) server configuration.
I flagged the question as off-topic and commented that it was, but however my comment was ***instantly*** deleted within 10 seconds of posting it.

Another user commented (I suspect they removed my comment, they *are* a 'superuser' in the tag) that:

```
Build automation is pretty well related to programming.
```

I disagreed and noted that the question is about ***server configuration***, of which such questions are off-topic on Stack Overflow.
The OP also commented and noted that the question is 50:50 server configuration and build automation, meaning their question is in a ***grey area***.

Are Bamboo server configuration questions on-topic for Stack Overflow, and was I wrong to flag the question as off-topic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting from the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):

> What topics can I ask about here?
>
> ... if your question generally covers…
>
> [...]
>
> - software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
> - a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

Bamboo is a build automation system / continuous integration/delivery tool. This is definitely related to software development enough to be on-topic here.

"Server configuration" questions that would be off-topic here are things like "How do I configure permissions on my Windows file server" that have nothing in particular to do with software development.

Comment: I agree. I don't know if Server Fault would consider these questions off-topic, but I don't think Stack Overflow should. CI servers are primarily (?) dev tools, so most questions about them are already on SO.