# Are configuration and/or network debugging questions on-topic?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, scope

I know there has been some discussion about this topic, but mostly related to specific topics: [Docker](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276579/should-docker-questions-go-on-stackoverflow-or-serverfault-or-superuser), [Bamboo](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277562/are-bamboo-server-configuration-questions-on-topic), [nginx](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262222/should-nginx-questions-be-on-stack-overflow), [webserver config files and rewrite rules](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261726/are-questions-about-webserver-config-files-and-rewrite-rules-on-topic)

All those are at least somewhat on-topic, because they might be specific to *someone's dev environment* - making them off-topic on ServerFault.

I assumed the opposite to also be true: If your problem is related to some service or infrastructure *provided to you* ([sending mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29672585/how-to-setup-email-notification-in-bugzilla), [connecting to a remote MySQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29574317/connect-netbeans-to-online-database)) then SO is the wrong place for the question.

I've flagged those two questions as off-topic, but both flags were disputed. I do understand that *disputed* is nothing to worry about too much, but still the community (partially, at least) proves my assumption wrong.

As reviewing should (imo) reflect the community's opinion and not my personal one, I'm unsure how to handle those types of questions.

Comment: Bugzilla is a software development tool.  The IP whitelisting question, meh.

Comment: @RobertHarvey But is that a good question about it?

Comment: The Bugzilla one?  No; I've closed it as "Too Broad."

Comment: OK, missed that. Sorry.

Comment: `Bugzilla is a software development tool.` sure, and that is usually on-topic. The reason I flagged it was because the problem is `Couldn't authenticate` on a remote mail server.